# iPhone iOS 7 - Background Download NSUrlSession

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, background-transfer

Welcome,

Now i'm implementing NSURLSession Download Process but i have an issue. Suppose i have a list and user clicked to download the 1st element in the list then decided to go back to previous view ,after that re-opened the download view again , how can i keep track of the progress of the background download as well as when i click on pause/continue the cell doesn't get update.

-2nd Q:
How can i track all currently downloading items and display them ?

Any idea how can i implement these features?

Comment: are you providing multiple downloading option in your app ???

Comment: yeah i do provide this option

Comment: then i guess you need to create an array of NSURLSession objects in appdelegate class and remove that object on completion.....

Comment: can you provide any example>?

Comment: You will got many examples on www.cocoacontrols.com